# Why does this incorrect memoized fibonacci function work?

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

Here's an incorrect implementation of memoized fibonacci:

```
long int fib(int n) {
    long int memo[100];
    if(n<2) {
        return n;
    }
    if(memo[n] != 0) {
        return memo[n];
    }
    else {
        memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        return memo[n];
    }
}
```

It is incorrect because the array `memo` is a brand new array each call and no memoization is occuring. The easiest fix is to make `memo` `static`. But, lo and behold, the code works!

I stepped through it in the debugger and `memo` is behaving as if it was static! It appears that the compiler generated code that is placing `memo` in the same memory space at every call as opposed to new fresh memory. Why is that?

Compiler used is Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12).

Comment: Welcome to the world of undefined behavior :D

Comment: it's a compiler quirk. Because memo isn't referenced until all the recursive calls have returned, new space for it isn't made on the stack until after the calls. But I suspect it isn't working all that well even if it may look like it. The initial values in the array will be junk.

Comment: **Undefined behavior** --> here it doesn't work: https://ideone.com/zeiHUM

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Is `memo` not referenced in the first `if`, before any further calls?

Comment: It's interesting the compiler doesn't complain about uninitialized memory being read. It likely would not allocate the space until it is written to

Answer (score 1):

It is UB, but if we assume that stack of a fresh thread contains only zeroes,
then all values in memo[100] can be zeroes or remains of previous call of the function.

The effective algorithm might work like the following:

```
long int memo[100] = {0};

long int fib(int n) {
    if(n<2) {
        return n;
    }
    if(memo[n] != 0) {
        return memo[n];
    }
    else {
        memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        return memo[n];
    }
}
```

Except each layer of recursion have own 'memo[100]'.

Comment: Nitpicking, but the initialization is not needed.

Comment: that is true. I added it to the example for clarifying that content is zeroes.